# autowiring selective beans into a list reference

Tags: spring-mvc, autowired

I have a service interface `I` with implementaions `I1,I2,I3...I10` out of which I want to use `I1-I5` to be autowired as a `List<I>` in controller class `C`. The `I6-I10` should not be be autowired. How can I achieve this. Moreover the I implementations are annotated @Service beans. I do not want to move them to xml declarations.

Comment: Remove the `@Service` annotation from `I6-I10`.

Comment: Cant do that sir... obviously if they are declared they are to be used else where in the application. I just want they should not be considered in my case.

Comment: If you're going to do it with annotations, you're going to have to change the source code every time. That's the strength of the XML config, everything is externalized.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the comment by mvb13 I have tried to weave a solution for the problem....

So I write a class extending ArrayList and mark it a Component

```
@Component("mysublist")
public class MyList extends ArrayList implements ApplicationContextAware
{
    @Value("comma.sep.eligible.beans.classnames")
    private String eligibles;

    private ApplicationContext appCtx;

    @PostConstruct
    public void init()
    {
        Map allBeans = appCtx.getBeansOfType(I.class);

        for(Object bean:allBeans.values())
        {
            if(eligibles.contains(bean.getClass().getSimpleName()))
            {
                add(bean);
            }
        }
    }

    public void setApplicationContext(ApplicationContext appCtx)
    {
       this.appCtx = appCtx;
    }
}
```

Now I can autowire the above bean in my required class definition as:

```
@Service
public class MyService
{
    @Resource(name="mysublist")
    private List<I> myReqdBeans;

    ......
}
```

*Please ignore the generics related implications in the code.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `@Qualifier`. It defines any subset that you need.

```
 @Autowired
 @Qualifier("MySubset")
 private List<I> list;
```

But I think you should move your bean definitions in xml to use `<qualifier ... />` property. I think you haven't another option to specify qualifier.

Comment: I had already implemented this.. but the whole thing is there are around 20 `I` beans so I don't want to declare them in XML.

Comment: I have another variant. You may extend ArrayList, annotate it with @Component and inject all beans that you need inside. After that you may inject this ArrayList where you want. Ugly solution, but may be it can be the option for you.

Answer (score 0):

The `@Qualifier` annotation should give you what you need. You need to apply it in two places:

- On the @Service beans that you wish to include in the sub-list
- On the @Autowired list injected into your controller

So addressing the `@Service` beans first:

```
 @Service
 @Qualifier("MySubList")
 public class MyService implements IMyService
 {

 }
```

And then within your Controller:

```
 @Controller
 public class MyController
 {

    @Qualifier("MySubList")
    @AutoWired
    private List<IMyService> myServices;

 }
```

This instructs Spring to `@AutoWire` all `IMyService` implementations `@Qualified` as "MySubList"

Comment: I didn't see usage of @Qualifier(I mean assigning of qualifier to bean like we do it in xml) on service in Spring documentation. So can you show please any references of using @Qualifier in such a manner.